# apt-get -f install removed nearly everything

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, apt, package-management, virtualbox

In an attempt to install some statistical software (SAS), I attempted to install virtual box while running in Ubuntu 12.04. I was unable to do so and prompted to use `apt-get -f install` which I did.

I was them prompted to type, `Yes, do as I say!` to allow the command to keep running. As it turns out, this removed nearly all applications and now I am unable to login to Ubuntu and kept getting a `failed to load session 'Ubuntu'` error.

Looking at other posts, I've tried to reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` and `unity`, both have made no difference.

I eventually got to a point where decided to try and upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 from a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> terminal. I eventually got a `system is running in low graphics mode` error and tried to install `nvidia`, `gdm`, and `lightdm` which amounted to nothing as it turns out. Now, I can not even reach the login screen of Ubuntu as it freezes before that. I have tried to reinstall gnome and gnome-panel and now I am out of ideas of what to do...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would try to use a LIVE CD/USB and Backup my Files and do a complete fresh installation.